# Can't change BLE-Services on Beetle-ESP32, old settings remain on board

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I'm using an Beetle-ESP32-C3 for a small project with BLE. I uploaded an example with PlatformIO (VisualStudioCode) for the first time ([https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-arduino-ide/].

Now, when I want to change anything on BLE (for example using another BLE-Service, BLE-Characteristics) I can upload the new programm without any problems to the ESP32. Even another example like that: [https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-ble-server-client/].

If I want to test the project with my BLE-Scanner (Android 13, "BLE-Scanner" or "LightBlue") I can connect without an problems to my ESP32-BLE-Server but I only see the BLE-Service from my first project.

I uploaded the new programm on an DOIT-ESP32-DEVKIT, it works without any problems. I tried to erase the flash from the Beetle-ESP32-C3 (PlatformIO, no problems) did a fresh upload of the new software, but still the BLE-Scanners show the old, first uploaded BLE-Service on the ESP32-C3.

How can I erase the BLE-Settings, Services, Characteristics on my ESP32-C3 so that I can upload my new software with other settings for BLE-Settings as in my first try.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everybody, the problem was not the ESP32, it was Android. After disconnecting the Bluetooth-Connection manually in the Android-Bluetooth-Settings ("forget BT device") and reconnecting over LightBlue, everything works as it should.
Maybe someone knows how to correctly announce the BLE service change on the ESP32 software side?

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to the bluetooth of the esp32 c3 kit you download a new program the connection will be lost so if you are using the celeste app it will ask you to reconnect just close the connection, as soon as the bluetooth of the esp32 c3 is ready it will appear in the celeste app it is not necessary to forget the previous connection it is important that you take into account the size of the name and the advertising data you use should not exceed the size of the buffer used everything should work correctly if the logic is correct, expressif-ide has several bluetooth project examples, you can create a project and use any of them for testing, I recommend nimble projects

Comment: Read his answer. The question was wrong. Vote to close it.